# @CsvBindByName - Binding column with alternate column name

Tags: java, opencsv

I have two csv sources to read data from. Both of the csv files provide the same data but with different name or column location. Is there a way to add @CsvBindByByName with "OR". For example, the headers of two files are as follows

> CSV 1 - RollNo, StudentName, Class, Age, PrimaryLanguage, ProjectName
>
> CSV 2 - Name, Class, PrimLang, EnrollmentNumber, Age, Project,
> AttendancePercentage

And I have to read both of the csv file information in same POJO.

```
public class StudentInfo{
@CsvBindByName(column = "RollNo")
private String rollNo;

@CsvBindByName(column = "StudentName")
private String studentName;

@CsvBindByName(column = "PrimaryLanguage")
private String primaryLanguage;

@CsvBindByName(column = "Class")
private String class;

@CsvBindByName(column = "ProjectName")
private String projectName;

@CsvBindByName(column = "Age")
private String age;

//getters and setters
}
```

Or is there an alternate way to achieve this. My code is working fine if I take only one csv header format. Thanks

Comment: Which version of opencsv are you using?

Comment: <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>5.4</version>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Profiles` in opencsv solves this problem, but it is only available from 5.4.

See [documentation](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#profiles) on `Profiles`

Below is a code snippet from the official documentation.

```java
public class Person {
  @CsvBindByNames({
    @CsvBindByName(column = "last name"),
    @CsvBindByName(profiles = {"customer 2", "customer 5"})
  })
  private String surname;

  @CsvBindByNames({
    @CsvBindByName,
    @CsvBindByName(column = "first name", profiles = "customer 1"),
    @CsvBindByName(column = "given name", profiles = "customer 2")
  })
  private String name;

  @CsvIgnore(profiles = "customer 2")
  @CsvBindByName(column = "middle initial")
  private char initial;

  @CsvBindByName(column = "salary", profiles = "customer 1")
  @CsvBindByName(column = "annual salary", profiles = "customer 2")
  @CsvNumber(value = "#0.00", profiles = "customer 1")
  @CsvNumber(value = "0.0#E0", profiles = "customer 2")
  private float salaryInUSD;

  @CsvBindByName(column = "height")
  @CsvNumbers({
    @CsvNumber("000"),
    @CsvNumber(value = "000cm", profiles = "customer 2")
  })
  private int heightInCentimeters

  // Accessor methods go here.
}


// Now, the profile can be used in the builder parse, see below.

List<Person> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Person>(inputfile)
  .withProfile("customer 1")
  .withType(Person.class)
  .build()
  .parse();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Karan - another way to say "thanks" is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). (But as it notes, accepting answers and voting are always optional.)

Comment: Is there a way that to use @PreAssignmentValidator with profiles? I tried something like this, didn't work(not adding symbol before annotation for restriction on formatting rules):
PreAssignmentValidator 
CsvBindByNames({
CsvBindByName,
CsvBindByName(column = "first name", profiles = "customer 1")
  })
  private String name

Comment: in this case the profiles should be known before. is there a way in which we can do dynamically i.e.  profile might not be known at build time. Can we just put aliases on column and at time of build parser can check either of name is present or not